# How to calculate fees in Plutus

Tags: plutus, fee

Let's say I have an `Ledger.Constraints.UnbalancedTx` with consumed regular UTxOs, script UTxOs and minting scripts, how can I calculate the fees of this transaction in **Plutus** ? This function would ideally also have the number of needed signatures as input argument.

My idea is to construct an `UnbalancedTx` that has all the UTxOs needed to cover fees and then balance it with the exact fee figure computed. I want to then export this transaction via the PAB and hand it over to Nami Wallet for signature.